# Oracle columns definition varchar(1) M (male) or F (female)

Tags: sql, oracle

I´m working with Oracle sql developer

I need to define a constraint for this column of a new data base:
`event_gender VARCHAR2(1)` 
It should accept 1 character: `M` (male) or `F` (female);  null not allowed

I defined the constraint in this way but doesn´t work:

```
 CONSTRAINT "Check_gender" CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(event_gender,'M'||'F'))
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: not sure but case might be the problem.

Comment: thanks to answer, it has the same problem in char

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To apply a constraint on Column 'event_gender' of Table 'XYZ', such that it accepts values as 'M' or 'F'. The constraint is named as 'Check_gender':

```
ALTER TABLE XYZ
add CONSTRAINT Check_gender
CHECK (event_gender IS NOT NULL AND event_gender IN ('M', 'F'));
```

To know more about [check constraints](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/check.php).

Comment: Perhaps the explanation will be so much helpful indeed +1

Comment: Pop a not null in there as well, perhaps.

Comment: @David: Edited , please let me know if the syntax is correct.

Comment: Hey David, It works perfectly even i already test it, thanks Wv.

Comment: @NoobUnChained That would work but "alter table mytab modify(event_gender not null);" works better for the optimiser. Oh, add a name to the check constraint as well, like "event_gender constraint mytab_chk_gender check(event_gender in ('M','F'))"

Comment: IMO it would be better to use a separate ordinary NOT NULL constraint, then use a simpler `event_gender IN ('M','F')` check constraint. That way, you'll get potentially more useful error messages ("NULL not allowed" vs. "Check constraint violated").